# Flatten layer description in "Hands-on Machine Learning"

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I am currently studying from *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow*. At some point in Chapter 10, the author demonstrates an MLP architecture to tackle the FashionMNIST problem:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
```

He then gives the following descripition for the flatten layer:

> Next, we build the first layer and add it to the model. It is a
> Flatten layer whose role is simply to convert each input image into a
> **1D array**: if it receives input data X, it computes **X.reshape(-1, 1)**.
> This layer does not have any parameters, it is just there to do some
> simple preprocessing. Since it is the first layer in the model, you
> should specify the input_shape: this does not include the batch size,
> only the shape of the instances. Alternatively, you could add a
> keras.layers.InputLayer as the first layer, setting shape=[28,28].

At this point, I can't understand why X.reshape(-1,1) is the chosen reshape action. Assuming that Flatten is performed separately for each batch (is that true?), it should transform (28,28) to (784,), yet the above reshape yields (784,**1**), which is not even a 1-D array. If that is correct, what is the purpose of this extra dimension with length 1?

EDIT: Considering also batch_size, it should transform (batch_size,28,28) to (batch_size, 784). However, the reshape results to (batch_size*784,1), which does not seem correct either.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found this in the Errata of the book (https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920142874). The correct is X.reshape(-1,28*28). I assume that the purpose of -1 is to keep the batch_size.

Note from the Author or Editor:

> Thanks a lot for your feedback.
> Indeed, this is an error. I should have written: "receives input data
> X, it computes X.reshape(-1, 28*28)". Fixed, thanks again!